# SharePoint custom logon form doesn't do anything on submit

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, forms-authentication, wss-3.0

I feel sure I'm missing something simple.. I had this working on a different server but now that I've migrated to a different server it doesn't seem to work. I have a WSS 3.0 site with forms-based authentication enabled and a custom logon form. When you go to the logon form and enter your username and password and click submit, it just seems to refresh the page, as if none of the codebehind is being executed in the postback. I have another control on that form--a button that, when clicked, should show a hidden panel. This button also does nothing now.

I have deployed the codebehind for the logon form to my bin directory (I know some people prefer the GAC but I did have it working this way previously).

I think this might have something to do with how IIS is set up, so maybe another way to phrase the question would be "what are the proper settings for a web site in IIS when FBA is used?"

Update: In at least one case of this, using Firefox caused the browser to display an error message (which was related to the trust level).

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint should be able to handle all of the configuration needed when setting up FBA. You shouldn't need to touch IIS at all and I wouldn't recommend it in case you end up in an unsupported state.

Check for errors in the ULS logs. Make sure you check and log **any exceptions that might occur** in the logon form. SharePoint can swallow these in certain situations.

If that fails try comparing web.config files between the web application on the working server and the new one. You could also try (after making a backup of course) deleting the FBA web application and re-extending it.